# 2D Coordinate Plane

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to sketch a plane to illustrate the relations between the Polar and the Cartesian coordinate systems, but I have no idea how to make it look good. I need some help, because all I've done is this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
    \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
    \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,1)            node[right] {$\vec{r}$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It's the closest I got.

here's how it should look like

[image]

All advises are fully appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw[very thin,color=gray] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
\coordinate (o) at (0,0);
\coordinate (r) at (2,1);
\coordinate (x) at (1,0);
\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
\draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[->] (o) -- (r) node[right] {$\vec{r}$}; 
\draw[dashed] (o|-r) node[left]{$y$} -- (r) -- (r|-o) node[below]{$x$};
\pic[draw, "$\varphi$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = x--o--r};
\node[below left] {$o$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with axis and a single vector with angle]

Comment: You beat me on this one ;) +1

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot! Where can I read about Tikz? There are so many Tikz- tutorials about circuits (for e. g. CircuiTikZ), but I din't find any good manuals on Tikz in general. Do you know any? Thank you again and have a nice day!

Comment: Yes - simply read the manual. You probably already have it on your computer as part of a LaTeX installation, or find it here: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en. The manual is huge, but well formed - just read the sections you need.

Answer (score 7):

I propose a solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot, pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
\psset{arrowinset=0.1, linejoin=1, ticks=none, labels=none, unit = 1.5cm}
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3)[$X$,-30][$Y$,60] \uput[dl](0,0){$O$}
\psline{->}(0,0)(2,1) \uput[30](2,1){$\vec{r}$}
\pnodes(0,0){O}(2,1){R}(2,0){H}
\pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=0.5, LabelSep=0.75\cite{}, arrows=->]{H}{O}{R}{$\varphi$}
\psCoordinates[linestyle=dashed, linewidth=0.5pt, markPoint=false](2,1) \uput[d](2,0){$x$}\uput[l](0,1){$y$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't even know about psticks package. Do you have any tutorials about this package? Thank you again and hope you have a nice day!

Comment: I don't know tutorials,  but you may look at the [pstricks web page](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) on CTAN. Furthermore, the documentation is very well done. For me, it has the advantage to be less verbose than tikz/pgf, and to use a latex-like syntax (actually it is some kind of interface between latex and postscript.)